# Search which database server running on localhost using python 2.7

Tags: python, database

I have installed two database server, MySQL and MongoDB. I have two functions written in Python 2.7 to connect to the databases, one for MySQL and one for MongoDB. Now, how do I know which database server is running on my localhost using python 2.7 so that i can call the appropriate connecting function?

Here is my connection function for both database servers:

```
import mysql.connector
from pymongo import MongoClient

conn=None

def mysql_make_connection():
    global conn
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='sk',user='root',password='SonuKumar@1')
    if conn.is_connected():
        print "Connection established"
    else:
        print "Connection Problem"

def mongo_make_connection():
    global conn
    conn=MongoClient('localhost')
```

Comment: Use `netstat` commands  is bettter than manual methods(Multiple  loopback ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking to see which one is running, perhaps a better way would be to use a try/except block to connect to the one most likely to be running. If that fails connect to the other one. So if mysql is the one most likely to be running, it could be something like this:

```
try:
    <code to connect to mysql>
except <connection error>:
    <code to connect to mongodb>
```